# Cross-referencing error in appendix

Tags: cross-referencing

I have a problem with cross-referencing in the appendix of the document I'm writing, `\ref` is not working properly and I only get `??`.

I'm using a LaTeX template for writing Ph.D. Thesis that can be found at [Texis page](http://gaia.fdi.ucm.es/grupo/projects/texis/). I'm working with Miktex2.8 and TeXnicCenter under Windows 7.

In the master document you can find:

```
\include{Capitulos/01Introduccion}
\include{Capitulos/02Metodologia}
\include{Capitulos/03ClimatologiaSST}
\include{Capitulos/04Sinoptica}
\include{Capitulos/05Modelizacion}
\include{Capitulos/06Conclusiones}

\appendix
\include{Apendices/01Rams}
\include{Apendices/02MapasSinopticos}
\include{Apendices/03MapasSST}
```

In chapter 2

```
E0996 & 11-12/09/1996 & 520 & 524.5 \\ \midrule
E1000 & 21-26/10/2000 & 376 & 570 \\ \midrule
E0502 & 06-08/05/2002 & 400 & 516 \\ \midrule
E1007 & 10-12/10/2007 & 400 & 404.4 \\ \midrule
\end{dataTable}
\end{center}
\caption[Listado de eventos precipitación]{Listado preliminar de eventos de precipitación torrencial en la \cv  (PMAX=Precipitación máxima)}
\label{cap2:tab:listaeventos}
\end{table}
```

and in appendix 3

```
  some text \ref{cap2:tab:listaeventos}
```

But the result is not a reference but `??`

Any suggestion? I have found some relatively similar questions here but none has fixed my problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) This should actually work. You of course compiled the document twice? Try to minimize the document until the error disappear to find the cause. See the thread about how to create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magic crystal ball guess: you're using `\includeonly` and haven't compiled chapter 2 since you put in the `\label`?

(One thing you could check is whether the string "cap2:tab:listaeventos" does appear in the file `02Metadologia.aux`, which it should.)

Comment: No, I used \include, not \includeonly and compiled the document 3 times. Maybe the point was the Miktex installation, I made an update and maybe something was broken. I have upgraded Miktex to version 2.9 and now it work's fine. As you said I have also checked that \label was located after \caption and that it appeared at 02Metodologia.aux